# How To get id of each Android notification?

Tags: xamarin, notifications, xamarin.android, android-notifications

Excuse me but other similar posts didn't help me.
 I use Xamarin and i appoint each notification an Id .
 I want to get clicked notification ID  in opened activity , and search it in my list and show related information
Thanks.

Comment: Nobody help؟ Please this is emergency issue Thank you

Comment: Please expand your question. It's not clear what you are asking. Please also give examples, suggested correct results, and your code, reduced to a small section to show the problem, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Graham. I got a list from WebService and for each item in it, i created a notification. each Item has id,text,image .

```
for (int i = 0; i < sobhan.arr_notify.Length; i++)
call_notify(context, sobhan.arr_notify[i].text, sobhan.int_32(sobhan.arr_notify[i].id));
```

And call_notify Method:

```
private static void call_notify(Context context, string message,int id)
        {
            Intent activityIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(Show_Notify));
            sobhan.notify_call_id = id;
            var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 0, activityIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
            builder.SetAutoCancel(true)
            .SetDefaults((int)NotificationDefaults.All)
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon_mini)
                   .SetContentTitle("دنیا طب دام")
                   .SetContentText(message)
                   .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                   .SetContentInfo("info");
            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
            manager.Notify(id, builder.Build());
        }
```

this "id" was Not set to own Notification And all notifications take last notification id .when "Show_Notify" activity calling , show image of last id.

Show_Notify Activity:

```
 var r = sobhan.show_arr_notify.FindAll(x => x.id == sobhan.notify_call_id.ToString());
if(r.Count>0)
            {
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(r[0].image, 0, r[0].image.Length);
 using (var os = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.CreateNew))
 {
bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, os);
}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the second notification id is the first notification id ,the third id is the second id... and when you click the notification the id will show on the image in `Show_Notify` Activity?  So id misplaced?

Comment: My question is why each notification doesn't keep own id ? in my case last id override previous ids and in Show_Notify activity i just get last id information

Comment: Replace this `PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 0, activityIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);` with  `PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, id, activityIntent, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);` [Refer to this, you can see the difference between CnacelCurrent and UpdateCurrent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html)

Comment: Thanks Joe, I will try and tell you result

Comment: excuse me Joe but How can i get selected notification Id now?

Comment: put the id into `intent` and get it in your `Show_Notify` activity. And there is no much code to show  how you handle the id. You can test my suggestion, I have tried it and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`MainActivity`:

```
[Activity(Label = "App26", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        Button bt1;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            initVicew();
        }
        private void initVicew()
        {
            bt1 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.bt);
            bt1.Click += Bt1_Click;
        }
        private void Bt1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int id=0;id<10;id++) {
                Intent activityIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(Activity1));
                activityIntent.PutExtra("id",""+id);
                var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, id, activityIntent, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);
                NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new  NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
                builder.SetAutoCancel(true)
                .SetDefaults((int)NotificationDefaults.All)
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Capture)
                       .SetContentTitle("دنیا طب دام")
                       .SetContentText(""+id)
                       .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                       .SetContentInfo("info");
                NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)this.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
                manager.Notify(id, builder.Build());
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("id="+id);
            }
        }
    }
```

`Main.axml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="click"
        android:id="@+id/bt" />
</LinearLayout>
```

`Activity1`:

```
[Activity(Label = "Activity1")]
    public class Activity1 : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your application here
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout2);
            string str = this.Intent.GetStringExtra("id");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(str);
        }
    }
```

`layout2`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: joe , my code is the same of yours except for loop between 0 to 10,whatever didn't work . major point is why every notification that added to notification bar doesn't keep own id ? until when we clicked on them, based their id , we get information .

Comment: Does my code works? If it works like what you want, please mark me firstly, and open one new case for your `why every notification that added to notification bar doesn't keep own id` question,  Thank you!